# Multiple subdomain facebook login Laravel

Tags: php, facebook, laravel

Redirects to main domain after logging into Facebook from sub domain.

How do I configure Facebook login to redirect URL to the sub domain it originated but not the original one?  example if I am in one.example.com I want it to redirect to one.example.com but not to example.com and I am using same database on all sub domains.

```
try {
    $providerUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}

$user = $this->createOrGetUser($providerUser, $provider);
Auth::login($user, true);

return redirect('/');
```

Answer (score -2):

The Facebook redirect URL can be specified in the `services.php` file of `config` folder of `Laravel`.

An example:

```
'facebook'  => [
        'client_id'     => 'xxxxxx',
        'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'redirect'      => 'provide_the_redirect_url_here',
    ],
```

Comment: i have used the same code as 
'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('FACEBOOK_URL'),
    ],
but how do i make it so that it is redirected to the sub domain it originated

Comment: You can provide the exact url where you want the user to be redirected to. For example , suppose I want the user who successfully logged in via `facebook` to the profile page , in that case the url can be something like `http://localhost:8000/profile` . This is just an example.  Hope it helps

Comment: redirect urls take you to the controller function that allows us to save the data provided by facebook and then its supposed to be redirected to the sub domain. It is how it should be, isn't it? or did i get the wrong idea?